# Why does one array display and the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array containing objects (`order`) and one containing a string (`test`). Using jquery I can get `test` to output to a `<div>` but cannot do the same for `order`.

I have tried using `console.log(order)` to confirm that there are values there before passing to `<div id="order">`.

Here is my code:

```js
var order = [];
var test = ["hello", "there"];

function updateCart(item) {
  var index = order.findIndex(i => i.id == item.id);
  if (index != -1) {
    order.splice(index, 1);
    order.push(item);
  } else {
    order.push(item);
  }
  console.log(order);
  console.log(test)
  $("#test").html(test);
  $("#order").html(order);

}

function plusOne(item) {
  if (item.qty < 10) {
    item.qty = item.qty + 1;
    document.getElementById((item.name).replace(/\s/g, '') + "Qty").innerHTML = item.qty;
  }
}

function minusOne(item) {
  if (item.qty > 0) {
    item.qty = item.qty - 1;
    document.getElementById((item.name).replace(/\s/g, '') + "Qty").innerHTML = item.qty;
  }
}

$("#HawaiianPlus").click(function() {
  plusOne(hawaiian);
  updateCart(hawaiian);
});

$("#HawaiianMinus").click(function() {
  minusOne(hawaiian);
  updateCart(hawaiian);
});

$("#NewYorkerPlus").click(function() {
  plusOne(newYorker);
  updateCart(newYorker);
});

$("#NewYorkerMinus").click(function() {
  minusOne(newYorker);
  updateCart(newYorker);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test"></div>
<div id="order"></div>
```

My product class looks like the below and order is an array with instances of these products:

```
class Product {
    constructor(id, name, price, qty) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price; 
    this.qty = qty;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `$("#order").html(order);` to *do* exactly?  The `.html()` function is going to convert the array to a string in the default way, which is probably not anything actually useful to your application.

Comment: I was just using that as a test of concept to be honest. I want to be able to access each element in the array say `order[0].name` etc

Comment: Can you create a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem? You're missing the buttons to click on, the definitions of variables like `hawaiian` and `newYorker`.

Comment: Try `$("#order").html(JSON.stringify(order))` to show something more useful.

Comment: Thank you for that, `JSON.stringify()` at least helped me to see something more useful. I will post a separate question that is more clearly defined and has a better example.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that you have some sensible values in your order array, like:

```
[
    {name: "book", value: "5"},
    {name: "cd", value: "6"},
    {name: "spray", value: "8"},
    {name: "pen", value: "1"},
]
```

As suggested in the comment section, you can put this into the html via

```
$("#order").html(order);
```

If you want only the names, then you can do something like this:

```
$("#order").html(JSON.stringify(order.map(item => item.name)));
```

or even put there new lines:

```
$("#order").html(JSON.stringify(order.map(item => item.name).join("\n")));
```